# Armeria Thread Leak

Tags: armeria

We are using armeria at work. We recently launched a new service into production and are finding that there is a thread leak somewhere. I am trying to identify the source. It looks like every time we make a call to any grpc endpoint new threads are launched which are not stopping / getting cleaned up. I tried to reproduce this locally and I am seeing this too. Although I have a feeling what I am seeing locally might be different to what we are seeing in production.
When I hit an endpoint locally I can see it launch a new thread which just stays like below -
armeria-eventloop-nio is the thread name. How come there is a new event loop thread created for every request made? I feel that we are doing something right. Could you help us by pointing us in the right direction please?

[![Armeria Threads for my service running locally][1]][1]

I downloaded the [grpc armeria example](https://github.com/line/armeria-examples/tree/master/grpc) and when I run that I see the same thing happening
[![Armeria threads for the grpc example][2]][2]

How come there is a new thread created for every request that doesn't get cleared up.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf6EB.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2KHN.jpg

Comment: https://javadoc.io/static/com.linecorp.armeria/armeria-javadoc/1.16.0/com/linecorp/armeria/server/ServerBuilder.html#workerGroup(int)

Comment: Thanks. Setting the workerGroup limits the number of threads.